# What is the "foo.1" file that Xcode creates in a command line tool?

Tags: xcode, macos

When I create a new Xcode project with the "command line tool" template, Xcode automatically adds a file with extension ".1" (e.g. Car.1 and main.m). What is the ".1" file?

Comment: The `.1` file is for a `man page`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the *source file* for the manpage of the new command line program, if you want to provide one.  Normally you don't, so you can safely delete it.

Comment: *source file* isn't quite right -- Xcode doesn't do anything to compile or otherwise convert the file into a manpage. It *is* the manpage file.

Comment: @Caleb Agreed; I couldn't think of a better term, however they are bit like HTML where `man` is the browser, and in that technology they are called "the source".